Require single-factor authentication in Xero OAuth2.0 sign-on for automated API calls
I am looking to have a TM1 / Planning Analytics server make API calls to the Xero cloud environment.
Following the API guidance provided by the Xero Developer site, I have been able to create a secure connection via OAuth2. This is attached to my personal username and necessarily involved a challenge on my mobile app before the Access Token and Refresh Tokens were issued. After that step, I am comfortable with using and updating the Refresh Token to get data from Xero.
Unlike app developers, I am trying to create an in-house solution that will not be placed on the Xero App portal. I am only trying to retrieve my own company's data via the API link.
I am trying to automate the OAuth2 process via the TM1 server. i.e. to remove multi-factor authentication that requires my mobile app.
If anyone has experience in doing this or a Xero developer is able to assist, that would be much appreciated.

MFA is compulsory but you should only need to do this once if you are including offline_access and refreshing the access token. You can use security questions, the alternative email option or a computer based authenticator if you don't want to use your mobile phone.
